# ¿Pérdida de precisión float->int?

Tags: c

¿Hay algún riesgo en reutilizar una función que devuelve un número en coma flotante si lo que necesito es un entero? Mi pregunta en el fondo es: ¿qué diferencia sobre la precisión hay entre estas tres cosas?

1)

```
float a,b;
int c;

c=(int)(a+b)
```

2)

```
double a,b;
int c;

c=(int)(a+b)
```

3)

```
int a,b;
int c;

c=a+b
```

Comment: Hola Guillermo. ¿Has investigado algo antes de hacer la pregunta? ¿Has llegado a alguna conlusion con pruebas de codigo? Mira [ask] para aprender a hacer preguntas válidas y de calidad. Un saludo

Comment: Depende del redondeo: Por ejemplo tienes que 3.4+3.4=6.8. Redondeando antes de sumar tienes 3+3=6, redondeando después de sumar tienes que 6.8 =>7 si tienes en cuenta el valor de los decimales. Si siempre ignoras (redondeo hacia abajo) el resultado será el mismo sumando dos números, con 3 números en cambio: 3.4+1.4+.2.3=7.1, que sería 7 mientras que 3+1+2=6. En cualquier caso la pregunta es sobre matemáticas y no sobre programación

Comment: @PabloLozano Se trata sobre la perdida de precisión por parte de la conversión a `int`, notese que: `3.4f != 3.4f` cuando se trata de `float`.

Comment: @PabloLozano No es sobre matemáticas, en los tres casos que he escrito estoy sumando enteros. Mi pregunta era qué pasa si manejo un dato entero declarado como flotante (y no como "int"), donde por "qué pasa" me refiero a si tiene alguna consecuencia hacer la conversión a "int"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que estás tratando de hacer es una conversión explícita de un tipo de dato flotante real (como `float` que tiene precisión simple, tu primer ejemplo, o `double` con precisión doble en el segundo ejemplo) a un valor entero con signo (`int`).

De acuerdo al estandar más reciente de C ([C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision))), esto ocurre al realizar esa conversión

> **§6.3.1.4 Flotante real y entero**
>
> 1) Cuando un valor finito real flotante es convertido a un tipo entero 
>   diferente a **_Bool**, la parte fraccional es descartada (es decir, el 
>   valor  es truncado a cero). Si el valor de la parte entera no puede ser
>   representado por el tipo de dato de entero el comportamiento es indefinido

Eso significa que para tu ejemplo 1) y 2) la conversión de la suma de los dos valores de tipo `float` o `double` a `int` 'descarta' el valor después del punto decimal y la parte entera es asignada a la variable de tipo `int` siempre y cuando el valor a asignar esté en el rango de valores posibles que puede tomar este tipo de dato (recuerda que esto depende de la arquitectura de la máquina, pero habitualmente es de 4 bytes en máquinas de 32 y 64 bits). Por ejemplo:

```
float a = 1.0;
float b = 2.5;
int c = (int)(a+b); /* 1.0 + 2.5 = 3.5, descarta el .5 y asigna a la variable c el valor entero 3
printf("%d",c); /* Imprime 3*/

double a = 723.666;
double b = 177.333;
int c = (int)(a+b); /* 723.666 + 177.333 = 900.999, descarta el .999 y asigna a la variable c el valor entero 900 */
printf("%d",c); /* Imprime 900 */
```

El caso problemático ocurre cuando la parte entera de la suma de los dos valores flotantes reales no se encuentra dentro del rango de valores válidos del tipo de dato `int`, por ejemplo, en una máquina donde `sizeof(int)` es 4 (4 bytes) el tipo de dato `int` acepta valores desde -(2^31)-1 = −2147483649 a 2^31 = 2147483648. De acuerdo al estandar, esta operación

```
double a = 1200000000.123;
double b = 1200000000.123;
int c = (int)(a+b); /* 1200000000.123 + 1200000000.123 = 2400000000.2460004 */
```

tiene un comportamiento indefinido, por cuanto la parte entera de 2400000000.2460004 (2400000000) es mayor al máximo valor posible de un tipo de dato `int` en esa arquitectura

Para el caso 3) no ocurre ningún tipo de conversión ni implícita ni explícita, la suma de dos tipos de datos `int` es un valor también `int`. Aquí el único problema que podría ocurrir es muy similar al caso antes mencionado: que la suma de los dos valores sea un número que no se encuentre en el rango definido por el tipo de dato `int`, pero esto no es un problema de precisión sino de [desbordamiento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: Muchas gracias, mi duda la has resuelto al hablar del desbordamiento.